# python code for parallel vectors

Tags: vectors, python

Wrote some Python code to verify if my Vectors are parallel and/or orthogonal. Parallel seems to be alright, orthogonal however misses out in one case. I thought that if the dotproduct of two vectors == 0, the vectors are orthogonal? Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
def isParallel(self,v):
    try:
        print self.findTheta(v,1)
        if (self.findTheta(v,1) == 0 or self.findTheta(v,1) == 180):
            return True
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return True

    return False

def isOrthogonal(self,v):
    print self.dotProduct(v)
    if self.dotProduct(v) == 0:
        return True

    return False

def dotProduct(self,v):
    dotproduct = sum([self.coordinates[i]*v.coordinates[i] for i in range(len(self.coordinates))])
    return dotproduct
```

Comment: Could you add some more detail? What is `findTheta(v,1)` and in particular why the number 1? Which case does not work for orthogonal vectors?

Comment: To see if two vectors are parallel in the first function, it suffice to check if all `self.coordinates[i]/v.coordinates[i]` for `i=1,...,length(self.coordinates)` are all equal.

Comment: Floating point rounding errors, perhaps? You might get some number which is very small, but not exactly equal to zero.

Comment: Equal, up to rounding precision, of course.

Comment: You should display the failing case.  Are the elements of the vectors integers or floating point?  For floats, comparisons using equality are dangerous.

Comment: good points. I'm taking the Linear Algebra brush-up course at Udacity and the answer for the following Vector instance is: not parallel (false), but orthogonal (true). However, the above code returns false on both accounts.

    v1=Vector([-2.328,-7.284,-1.214])
    v2=Vector([-1.821,1.072,-2.94])
    print 'Orthogonal: '+str(v1.isOrthogonal(v2))
    print 'Parallel: '+str(v1.isParallel(v2))

Comment: findTheta finds the theta value, the 1 or 0 parameter at the end specifies whether to return RAD or degrees.

 def findTheta(self,v,degrees):
  cosinus = self.dotProduct(v)/(self.magnitude()*v.magnitude())
  theta = math.acos(cosinus)
  if degrees:
   theta=math.degrees(theta)
  return theta

Comment: Hans Lundmark had it correct, it's a float rounding error that caused it to false negative. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def isOrthogonal(self,v,tolerance=1e-10):
    if abs(self.dotProduct(v)) < tolerance:
        return True

    return False
```

the above code runs fine, as there are chances of rounding errors in my original code. Hans Lundmark got is straight: floating point rounding errors can cause the code to falter and produce false negatives.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with 3D vectors, you can do this concisely using the toolbelt [vg](https://github.com/lace/vg). It's a light layer on top of numpy and it supports single values and stacked vectors.

```
import numpy as np
import vg

v1 = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
v2 = np.array([-2.0, -4.0, -6.0])

vg.almost_collinear(v1, v2)
# True
```

I created the library at my last startup, where it was motivated by uses like this: simple ideas which are verbose or opaque in NumPy.